# Does electrical field intensity force equation apply to non-circular objects?

Tags: physics, electricity

I read that Couloumb's law, which replaces the force [image: in this equation] in order to measure electrical intensity at any point in space around unit charge only applies to circular objects.

Does that mean that if I have some rectangular piece of metal positively charged, I wont be able to measure what is the intensity of its field at some random point in space? If so, how can I change the equation to solve such an occurrence? I suppose it might be somehow related to finding center of the gravity for the charge inside that rectangular piece of metal?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you measure the field intensity close to the object, you will notice different readings near the corners due to fringing.  But as you retreat far away from the object (about a factor of 10 times the dimension of the object), the fringing effect will become unnoticeable and it will look just like a sphere (the circular object you mentioned?).  Coulomb's law is absolute and cannot be modified: it's the definition of the strength of an electric field i.e. the field intensity!